# How to remove padding Chart js

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, web, charts

I use Chart js with options:

```
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      }]
    }
  }
```

How to remove this padding?
I cant find this option in documentation.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that the url-text is causing this problem, you should use a shorter text. Also if you add a plunker demo I'm sure your question will be answered faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `minRotation` or `maxRotation` of `tick` to change the angel of the labels:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        minRotation: 90 // angle in degrees
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding is due to the first label. If you reduce the labels, everything will work just fine. Because the canvas element has to fill in the space provided and cannot go beyond the canvas size.